# CSS (bootstrap) : active/current tabbed menu item not highlighted

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm modifying a bootstrap theme and have one tricky little problem (which also appears in the unmodified theme) in that when the page first loads, the active/current tab does not display as such. The tab marked FIRST should display with a cyan background when the page loads, but instead it only changes from grey to cyan when clicked.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="service_tabe_menu nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class = "current"><a href="#first" aria-controls="first" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">FIRST</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#second" aria-controls="second" role="tab" 
  data-toggle="tab">SECOND</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#third" aria-controls="third" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">THIRD</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS like this:

```
.service .nav-tabs>li>a{
    text-align: center;
    color: #444444;
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left:10px;
    background: url(../images/skmenubg.png) no-repeat top center;
    border:0px;
    transition: all 0.6s;
}
.service_tabe_menu.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus{
    background: url(../images/skmenubgh.png) no-repeat top center;
    width:150px;
    height: 80px;
    color:#fff;

}
.service_tabe ul li a:hover{
   background: url(../images/skmenubgha.png) no-repeat top center;
   color:#fff;
}

.service_tabe_menu li nav nav-tabs li.current a:active {
   background: url(../images/skmenubgh.png) no-repeat top center;
   color:#fff;
}

.service_tabe ul li a i{
    font-size:2rem;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}

.service .tab-content{
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

Am I going about it the wrong way?
edit: update based on feedback

Comment: Your css does not target the `.current`. `ul.tabs li.current` is what I think is supposed to be targeting it, but there is no `ul` with class `tabs` in your markup

Comment: I tried also with `ul.nav-tabs li.current` and `ul.service_tabe_menu nav nav-tabs li.current`  but with no improvement

Comment: Then update your code to that because right now the markup does not match css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some letters/classes in your stylesheet. 
[codepen with fixes](https://codepen.io/1bladesforhire/pen/gzmLjV)

You want to make sure that you are providing the correct classes for the javascript, so you are using active and current, usually you will only have one. You need to assign the active class in the html so that the css/js knows what is active on loading the page. Additionally, you would target the li as either `.service_tabe_menu li` or `ul li` since the ul has the class service_tabe_menu, you don't use `.service_tabe_menu ul` because there is no ul inside that class. Hope this helps.

Comment: Assigning both active and current in the HTML and adapting the code based on your example leaves me with the same result - the FIRST tab is grey (skmenubg.png) on page load and turns cyan (skmenubgh.png) on hover. The other tabs are grey and turn purple (skmenubgha.png) on hover. So there is a difference in the way the tabs behave but I'm still unable to have the acive tab show as active (cyan) when the page loads.

Comment: In your example, the behaviour is similar. The word FIRST is not highlighted when the page loads so it's not obvious which tab is active. It changes to cyan on hover while the others change to red. The green background is never seen.

Comment: sorry for confusion the wording was a little hard to follow. were you able to figure it out or do you need me to add more to the codepen?

Comment: just remove the :hover from the a tag and you will have the on load cyan. https://codepen.io/1bladesforhire/pen/gzmLjV

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I had removed the a:hover entirely several times over when testing but not just the :hover.
You wouldn't believe how long I spent on this one tiny thing compared to the rest of the page!

Comment: I have a weird corolloray bug though, now. In the responsive (5" phone) version of the site, when I enable one of the tabs it no longer keeps the responsive-defined width of 75px but expands to 150px. The first tab is 75px and highlighted on loading the page. Weird

Comment: It's specifically the focus part which is not resizing right. As soon as I tap elsewhere on the screen, the active tab reverts to the proper width of 75px

Comment: Just to close this off. For some unknown reason, as soon as the tab gets focus it adopts the width property of a tablet as defined elsewhere in the responsive CSS. Commenting out the tablet section entirely fixes the problem on the phone, but at what cost...

Comment: ` .service_tabe_menu.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus{` looks like you're missing a class on the focus, so it may be defined elsewhere. try adding the service_tabe_menu to the .nav-tabs like in the first option. Good luck.